# FineUploader issue on iOS8 Beta5

Tags: html, ios8, fine-uploader

When using iOS7 the demo page at http://fineuploader.com/demos.html uploads works fine however on iOS8 Beta 5 I’m unable to select an image to upload, has any testing been done with iOS8 as its due for release soon (few weeks)?

Comment: This is probably more appropriate to post in the Fine Uploader GitHub repo issue tracker at https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/new.

Comment: Thank you Ray, I’ll look and see if I can post the issue at the GitHub repo

Answer (score 0):

Looks like iOS8 beta has some big issues with `<input type="file">` elements.  The presence of a `multiple` attribute prevents images from being selected.  Discussion continuing at https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1269.